# Validar un botón en Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo una tienda online. Cuando estoy en confirmar pedido que es el último paso para realizar el pago hay un checkbox con el que tienen que aceptar el contrato. La cuestión es que con las validaciones de Laravel creo que no puedo hacerlo, ya que cuando doy a confirmar botón me redirige a una página externa que es la pasarla de pago.

He probado hacerlo con Jquery, consigo poner en disable el botón hasta que pulso el checkbox, pero quiero que si le dan click al botón de enviar y no se a dado al checkbox salte una alerta con que tienen que aceptar el contrato. No se si se os ocurre otra idea, ya que al estar disabled el botón no puedo añadirle ningún evento.

```
$( '#aceptaContrato' ).on( 'click', function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    // Hacer algo si el checkbox ha sido seleccionado
    $(".btnConfirmar").prop('disabled', false);
   } else {
    // Hacer algo si el checkbox ha sido deseleccionado
    $(".btnConfirmar").prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Fragmento HTML:

```
<form action="{{ url('redsys') }}" method="get" name="confirmar_pedido" id="confirmar_pedido">
  <div class="col-12 partit">
     <h2><span class="postextoEquipo">CONTRATO PROVISIONAL</span></h2>
       <p>Tiene que confirmar el contrato provisional. Una vez vayan a entregarle el equipo a sus instalaciones recibirar el contrato original y una copia.</p>
      <div class="contratoProvisional">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <span>{{$usuario->name}}</span>, officiis a magnam ipsa soluta nesciunt autem labore deleniti neque nisi vel aperiam laboriosam! Iure rem magni explicabo <span>{{$usuario->cif}}</span>. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta voluptates architecto accusamus, maiores nisi unde molestias voluptatem ipsa reprehenderit alias eum nam dolorem debitis sit <span>{{$usuario->negocio}}</span>, facere ab nobis.
        <br>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit hic nostrum delectus, officiis a magnam ipsa soluta nesciunt autem labore deleniti neque nisi vel aperiam laboriosam! Iure rem magni explicabo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta voluptates architecto accusamus, maiores nisi unde molestias voluptatem ipsa reprehenderit alias eum nam dolorem debitis sit id iusto, facere ab nobis.
        </div>
        <div class="positionTerminos10">
           <input name="checkbox" class="chzxc" type="checkbox" id="aceptaContrato">
           <div class="labTerm21">He leído y acepto los terminos del contrato</div>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>

<div class="form-group">
<h4 class="titDirec">Dirección de instalación</h4>
  <select class="form-control inputLlama" name="entrega" id="entrega" style="background: #fff;padding-right: 0px; font-size: 13px;" required>
   @forelse ($direcciones as $list)
      <option value="{{ $list->id }}"> {{ $list->direccion }} {{ $list->numeros }} - {{ $list->postal }} {{ $list->nameProvincia }}</option> 
        @empty
          <option value=""> No tienes direcciones </option> 
        @endforelse
  </select>
</div>


<a href="#addDireccion" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addDireccion" id="" class="addDireccion903"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Añadir dirección</a>

@csrf
<input type="hidden" name="total" value="{{ $total }}">
<input type="hidden" name="idusuario" value="{{$usuario->id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="persona" value="{{$usuario->name}}">
<input type="hidden" name="dni" value="{{$usuario->cif}}">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{$usuario->email}}">

<div class="">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnConfirmar" disabled>Realizar pago</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Estoy probando así en el controlador del método de pago:

```
return [
  'checkbox' => 'accepted',
];
```

Pero lo único que hace es mostrarme el código y siempre en acepted.

Comment: Agrega una muestra mínima funcional del  HTML

Comment: haz la validacion en el submit, captura el valor del checkbox y si no esta marcada que entre por el prevent default y muestre el modal con la advertencia

Comment: Una manera de hacer esto es comprobar el value del checkbox al enviar el formulario. Si asignas un valor al checkbox (ejemplo, value="1") desde el controlador puedes comprobar si ese valor te llega, y si lo hace lo mandas a la otra página, y sino redireccionas a la misma con un mensaje de error.

Comment: Hola @BetaM ya he añadido un fragmento del HTML. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo e solucionado del siguiente modo. Con el `$request->validate` podemos comprobar lo que llega por el request, además de que le puedo poner el mensaje de error que mostrar.

Si teneis alguna sugerencia mejor, estoy abierto a aprender más sobre este tema.

```
$request->validate([
   'aceptaContrato' => 'accepted',
   'entrega' => 'required',
   'facturacion' => 'required'
  ], [
   'aceptaContrato.accepted' => 'Tienes que aceptar el contrato para poder realizar el pago.',
   'entrega.required' => 'Es necesaria una dirección de instalación.',
            'facturacion.required' => 'Es necesaria una dirección de facturación.'
]);
```